# What does 'lump' mean in the phrase 'You can like it or lump it'

Tags: meaning

What does 'lump' mean in the phrase 'You can like it or lump it'?

As in the example: 'I am going on holiday and if you don't agree you can like it or lump it.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"lump" as a verb also means carry, especially something heavy (at least in Northern English)  - so you can like it or have to carry it anyway

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lump--2?region=us&rskey=dFwXTh&result=2):

> **lump** (/,ləmp/) *verb* [*with object*] (**lump it**) *informal*:
>   accept or tolerate a disagreeable situation whether one likes it or not:
>   *you can **like it or lump it** but I’ve got to work*

Comment: Quite commononly found in informal British speech. (By the way, I see your link is to Oxford Dictionaries. That is not the OED, which can be found here <http://www.oed.com/> and which requires a subscription.)

Comment: The trouble with that definition is that it's from the phrase

Comment: @MartinBeckett, you're right. In retrospect, it seems obvious that this was not a good answer. Thank you.

Comment: Chamber’s Slang Dictionary gives ‘to accept a situation, willingly or not’. The OED has it under its second entry for ‘lump’, meaning, in contrast to ‘like’, ‘to be displeased at (something that must be endured)’ and gives the etymology, a little mysteriously, as ‘of symbolic sound’.